# Failed to fetch error in javascript with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browserify

So I've been fiddling with this for days and would love any guidance. I want to embed JSON data (accessed via [multichain-node](https://github.com/scoin/multichain-node/blob/development/test/test.js) wrapper) on my html page. Here is my js file (which I use browserify on to make compatible for client side)

```
"use strict";

var multichain = require("multichain-node")({
    port: 6790,
    host: '104.236.99.212',
    user: "multichainrpc",
    pass: "8617E5uRperkAf1BifL9uAhZJDVWvC5Ngt2bdJ4eQDkJ"
  });

multichain.getInfo((err, info) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(info);
})
```

In my research a CORS issue came up, so I adjusted my app.js file to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');

})
```

But I still get this error thrown from multichain.getInfo

> TypeError: Failed to fetch
>       at TypeError (native)

ANY input would be much appreciated. It is not an issue with the server, as when I directly try to print the information in the terminal vs in the browser I have no problems.

Comment: Could you try to add `charset="utf-8"` to the `.html` files? I saw [this](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-testtools/issues/11) and it looks like the same error, which comes from a conflit with "uglyfyJS", maybe you could have a conflict with "browserify". I am saying that just because you said "ANY input".

Comment: Just tried adding that but no luck, but thank you for the input. At least investigating browserify induced errors lets me bang my head against a new problem :)

Comment: I guess you've fixed it by now, but you are also missing `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in your response.  This [cors server flowchart](https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png) is a handy reference for what you need to set and when you need to set it.